# Fixed positioned sidebar alignment

Tags: html, css

I have a sidebar that I am trying to get sticky on my page http://r1creative.net/station22/  I have a script in the footer that changes it from static to fixed when the page gets to a certain point. Thats working fine but the problem Im having is that when it switches, it changes how the div holds the nav ribbons and they dont "hang" over the side anymore.  Ive tried messing with different combinations, but nothing could keep the scroll effect, and leave the ribbons looking the same.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Here is an example of the sidebar I was trying to replicate http://www.apple.com/finalcutpro/all-features/#incredible-performance

Comment: Ill update this and say that the ribbons stay the same, but the nav doesnt stay in the same position once it switches to fixed...it jumps a little bit and isnt smooth like the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is with your "float right"

```
#navwrap {
    width: 295px;
    float: right; // remove 
    height: 679px;
    background: #F3F3F3;
    position: relative;
    left: 27px; // Add this left positioning
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 20px 0 0;
    box-shadow: -4px 4px 8px #444;
}
```

Let me know of that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your sidebar gets fixed to the left side of the page. Just add `left: 28px` to the element when you set its position to fixed. Better yet, set a class and just add the class with JavaScript, rather than adding each CSS element.